# JUnit test returning null and false

Tags: java, junit

So I am practicing parameterised tests in JUnit. I created this class:

```
public class Operation {

    public Operation() {

    }

    public int add(int value, int num) {
        int ans = value + num;
        return ans;
    }

    public int subtract(int value, int num) {
        int ans = value - num;
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Nothing special, just some methods to run some tests on.

I have this test class here:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class OperationTest {

    private int value;
    private int num;

    public OperationTest(int expected, int value, int num) {
        this.value = value;
        this.num = num;
    }

    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Collection primeNumbers() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
                { 4, 2, 2 },
                { 66, 6, 60 },
                { 20, 19, 1 },
                { 82, 22, 50 },
                { 103, 23, 80 }
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Operation o = new Operation();
        assertTrue(value == o.add(value, num));
    }

}
```

finally I have a class to run my tests:

```
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

public class TestRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(OperationTest.class);
        for(Failure f : result.getFailures()) {
            System.out.println(f.toString());
        }

        System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());
    }
}
```

When I run this, the output is:

```
test[0](OperationTest): null
test[1](OperationTest): null
test[2](OperationTest): null
test[3](OperationTest): null
test[4](OperationTest): null
false
```

I am expecting all of them to be true, given that { 4, 2, 2 } means expecting 4 from 2 and 2 which are given as parameters to the add method in the Operation class...I am guessing that this is probably not the right way to do it...

I would be grateful on your insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using `expected` anywhere - not even making it part of the state of the class. Your assertion here:

```
assertTrue(value == o.add(value, num));
```

... is not asserting what you want it to. It's only going to work when `num` is 0. Look at it carefully.

You should have:

```
// final is optional here, of course - but that's what I'd do, anyway :)
private final int expected;
private final int value;
private final int num;

public OperationTest(int expected, int value, int num) {
    this.expected = expected;
    this.value = value;
    this.num = num;
}
```

And then:

```
assertTrue(expected == o.add(value, num));
```

Or better (much clearer diagnostics):

```
assertEquals(expected, o.add(value, num));
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't resist adding that space that would make the code being rendered as code.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux: No problem at all - it's a perfectly valid edit :)

Comment: I know, but right now, I'm the one who edited your post. You could have been the only author.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to express, thank you very much :) I don't know why I left expected hanging there doing nothing, I'll focus more next time.

Answer (score 2):

How can `value == value + number` ever be true, given that `value` nor `number` is zero (as we can see by looking at your test numbers)? You clearly missed something simple in the logic. I guess you need a third parameter that expresses the expected result, so you can do:

```
expected == o.add(value, number);
```

Comment: @JonSkeet: I admit, I will narrow down the situation :P